# NSWindowController subClass - Init is Called twice

Tags: cocoa, nswindowcontroller

im very new in cocoa development and I'm trying to load a Window. 
I will explain my problem.

When the user click the menuItem I use the following code to load my window

```
if ( !cadastroContasController )
{
    cadastroContasController = [[cadastroContas alloc]init];
    [cadastroContasController SetMenuItem:sender];
}
if ( ![[cadastroContasController window] isVisible] )
{
    NSLog(@"!isVisible");
    [cadastroContasController showWindow:nil];
}
```

I my cadastroContas class looks like this:

```
@interface cadastroContas : NSWindowController 
{
    NSMenuItem *mnuCommand;
    IBOutlet NSComboBox *cmbSelecao;
    IBOutlet NSTextField *txtNome;
    IBOutlet NSTextField *txtSaldoInicial;
    IBOutlet NSTextField *txtAnotacoes;
}


- (void)windowDidBecomeKey:(NSNotification *)notification;
- (BOOL)windowShouldClose:(id)sender;
- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification;
- (void)SetMenuItem:(NSMenuItem*) menu;
- (NSMenuItem*) MenuItem;

@end
```

and the implementation is

```
@implementation cadastroContas

-(void)windowDidLoad
{
NSLog(@"windowDidLoad");
[mnuCommand setState:NSOnState];
}

-(id)init
{
    self = [super initWithWindowNibName:@"cadastroContas"];
NSLog(@"Init self=%p", self);
return self;
}
-(void)dealloc
{
NSLog(@"Dealoc=%p", self);
[super dealloc];
}

- (void)windowDidBecomeKey:(NSNotification *)notification
{
NSLog(@"windowDidBecomeKey window=%p", [self window]);
}

- (BOOL)windowShouldClose:(id)sender
{
NSLog(@"windowShouldClose Window=%p", [self window]);
NSLog(@"mnuComando=%p GetMenuItem=%p", mnuCommand, [self MenuItem] );
if ( mnuCommand )
{
    [mnuCommand setState:NSOffState];
}
return YES;
}

- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification
{

NSLog(@"windowWillClose  Window=%p", [self window]);
NSLog(@"mnuCommand=%p GetMenuItem=%p", mnuCommand, [self MenuItem] );   
[self dealloc];
}

- (void)SetMenuItem:(NSMenuItem*) menu
{
mnuCommand = menu;
}

- (NSMenuItem*) MenuItem
{
    return mnuCommand;
}

@end
```

When the menu was clicked, I received two messages "Init" and I don't know why.
Exemple:

```
[2223:a0f] Init self=0x10014fe40
[2223:a0f] Init self=0x10011f5a0
```

The second message let the "`[cadastroContasController SetMenuItem:sender];`" useless.

So, I need help to understand whats going on..

Another thing, `[[cadastroContasController window]` is always returning `NULL(0x0)`!!, but inside my controller i can handle it (it isn't null).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means you inited two instances, as shown by your logging of the `self` pointer: Notice that the value is different between the two messages.

You can use the Allocations instrument in Instruments to see what caused each window controller to be instantiated.

Usually, this problem happens when you create one of these in the nib and the other one in code. In the case of a window controller, the one you create in code should be the owner of its nib; you should not create another window controller as an object in the nib.

> Another thing, `[[cadastroContasController window]` is always returning `NULL(0x0)`!!, but inside my controller i can handle it (it isn't null).

The window controller whose `window` outlet you set to the window is the one that is returning non-`nil`. The window controller whose `window` outlet you didn't set is the one that is returning `nil`.

Following from what I said above, after deleting the window controller you created in the nib, you should connect your File's Owner's `window` outlet to the window.

Comment: Hi, Peter Thank you by the answer.

Comment: Hi, Peter Thank you by the answer. I've changed my source code a little bit, first the File's Onwer, now is type 'cadastroContas', I've linked all outlets to the File's Onwer. (So, my ControllerClass has no outlets linked). Now, it seens to be working fine, the init is called twice, but the dealloc is called twice too (so, I don't have a problem)..  You said to delete the window controller that I created in the nib, could you explain more ? I din't realize what do you mean.

Comment: @Fabio Araujo: The “cadastroContas” that you created in the nib. (You mention “my ControllerClass has no outlets linked”—that's the one you need to delete.)