# How to Subclass NSWindowController

Tags: objective-c, macos, nswindowcontroller, apple-documentation

I was replacing the deprecated `+(BOOL)loadNibNamed:owner:` method in our macOS app with a more standard `initWithWindowNib` approach and came across the Apple guide about *Document-Based App Programming Guide for Mac*. One section particularly drew my attention: [An NSWindowController Subclass Manages Nib Files](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocBasedAppProgrammingGuideForOSX/KeyObjects/KeyObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011179-CH3-SW10)

For records it say:

> An `NSWindowController` object expects to be told what nib file to load
>   (through its initWithWindowNib... methods) because it is a generic
>   implementation of the default behavior for all window controllers.
>   However, when you write a subclass of `NSWindowController`, that
>   subclass is almost always designed to control the user interface
>   contained in a particular nib file, and your subclass would not work
>   with a different nib file. It is therefore inconvenient and
>   error-prone for the instantiator of the subclass to have to tell it
>   which nib file to load.
>
> This problem is solved by **overriding the `init` method to call the
>   superclass’s `initWithWindowNibName:` method with the correct nib name**.
>   Then instantiators just use `init`, and the controller has the correct
>   nib file. You can also override the `initWithWindowNib...` methods to
>   log an error, as shown in Figure 2-4, because no instantiator should
>   ever try to tell your subclass which nib file to use. It is a good
>   idea for any `NSWindowController` subclass designed to work with a
>   specific nib file to use this technique. You should do otherwise only
>   if you are extending just the basic functionality of
>   `NSWindowController` in your subclass and have not tied that
>   functionality to any particular nib file.
>
> [image: Figure 2-4 Loading a nib file that is controller specific]

Pretty reasonable, let's try it.

---

Note: There is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11768511/initializing-an-nswindowcontroller-subclass) related to the same documentation section, but it has a different problem, asks a different question and is not using Modern Objective-C syntax.

---

My MainWindowDelegate.h now has:

```
- (instancetype)init NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
- (instancetype)initWithWindow:(nullable NSWindow *)window NS_UNAVAILABLE;
- (nullable instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder NS_UNAVAILABLE;
- (instancetype)initWithWindowNibName:(NSNibName)windowNibName NS_UNAVAILABLE;
- (instancetype)initWithWindowNibName:(NSNibName)windowNibName owner:(id)owner NS_UNAVAILABLE;
- (instancetype)initWithWindowNibPath:(NSString *)windowNibPath owner:(id)owner NS_UNAVAILABLE;
```

And MainWindowDelegate.m now has:

```
- (instancetype)init {

    self = [super initWithWindowNibName:@"MainWindowWin"];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.

    }

    return self;
}
```

---

The only available initializer from the `AppDelegate` is correctly the `init` (if I try to use `initWithWindowNibName` then I get the error `'initWithWindowNibName:' is unavailable`). So far so good and it works pretty nicely.

But now I have a bunch of **warnings**...

For `- (instancetype)init {` line

> Designated initializer missing a 'super' call to a designated initializer of the super class

For `self = [super initWithWindowNibName:@"MainWindowWin"];` line

> Designated initializer invoked a non-designated initializer

---

If this is the suggested Apple approach to subclassing NSWindowController why all these warnings? Am I missing the point? How to fix the warnings and maintain only `init` initializer availability?

Comment: Apple does not suggest using `NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER` and `NS_UNAVAILABLE`.

Comment: Yes, they suggest to log an error... that is not solving the problem of being still able to see and use `initWithWindowNibName` from another class. With Modern Objective-C syntax we can accomplish this with `NS_UNAVAILABLE`.

Comment: You can't use documentation from 2012 and Modern Objective-C syntax.

Comment: Isn't answer questions about topics not covered by outdated or incomplete documentation part of the reason why we are all here? 